# issues aggregating data postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a sql query that runs just fine locally, which is supposed to group log data by hour, resource and region into a separate table and remove the processed rows from the current table. However, I'm facing the issue of the aggregated data amounting to 300-600k `requests` per hour when in reality we have ~1 million per 24h or about 50k requests per hour. So for some reason the aggregated values are consistently too high. Furthermore, it's not throwing any errors or anything indicating something's not working as intended.
That's why I'm kinda stumped about how to fix this, seeing as there are no errors and I can't reproduce the issue locally.

The DB is running on postgresql version 15.1.0.121 and that's my query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

WITH daily AS (
SELECT
date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as timestamp,
region,
resource,
AVG(response_time)::FLOAT8 AS avg_res_time,
COUNT(*) AS requests
FROM
24h_metrics
WHERE
timestamp < date_trunc('hour', :before::TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY
region,
date_trunc('hour', timestamp),
resource
)

INSERT INTO aggregate_metrics SELECT * FROM daily;

DELETE FROM
24h_metrics
WHERE
timestamp < date_trunc('hour', :before::TIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
```

I wrapped it in a transaction suspecting concurrency issues but the values have remained consistently (too) high...
Any ideas what could be the issue are greatly appreciated!

---

Queries I ran showing differences between live and aggregated data:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp),
  COUNT(*) AS per_hour
FROM
  24h_metrics
GROUP BY 
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp)
ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', timestamp) DESC
```

outputs (expected values)

```json
[
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T21:00:00.000Z, perHour: '10135' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T20:00:00.000Z, perHour: '70147' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T19:00:00.000Z, perHour: '67690' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T18:00:00.000Z, perHour: '64974' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T17:00:00.000Z, perHour: '64826' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T16:00:00.000Z, perHour: '78099' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T15:00:00.000Z, perHour: '61834' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T14:00:00.000Z, perHour: '67149' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T13:00:00.000Z, perHour: '68458' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T12:00:00.000Z, perHour: '55620' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T11:00:00.000Z, perHour: '81753' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T10:00:00.000Z, perHour: '73078' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T09:00:00.000Z, perHour: '67346' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T08:00:00.000Z, perHour: '52988' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T07:00:00.000Z, perHour: '63478' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T06:00:00.000Z, perHour: '61920' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T05:00:00.000Z, perHour: '75885' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T04:00:00.000Z, perHour: '63417' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T03:00:00.000Z, perHour: '77517' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T02:00:00.000Z, perHour: '61402' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T01:00:00.000Z, perHour: '74864' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-26T00:00:00.000Z, perHour: '62362' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-25T23:00:00.000Z, perHour: '62987' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z, perHour: '60494' },
  { dateTrunc: 2024-01-25T21:00:00.000Z, perHour: '64995' }
]
```

However, once the data is aggregated there's the issue:

```
SELECT 
timestamp,
SUM(aggregate.requests) AS have
FROM
aggregate_metrics AS aggregate
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

outputs values much higher than what I'd expect:

```json
[  
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T20:00:00.000Z, have: '413301' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T19:00:00.000Z, have: '392962' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T18:00:00.000Z, have: '350294' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T17:00:00.000Z, have: '362352' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T16:00:00.000Z, have: '304558' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T15:00:00.000Z, have: '409682' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T14:00:00.000Z, have: '407799' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T13:00:00.000Z, have: '427952' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T12:00:00.000Z, have: '413406' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T11:00:00.000Z, have: '550886' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T10:00:00.000Z, have: '425222' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T09:00:00.000Z, have: '414875' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T08:00:00.000Z, have: '435540' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T07:00:00.000Z, have: '397072' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T06:00:00.000Z, have: '383173' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T05:00:00.000Z, have: '447108' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T04:00:00.000Z, have: '414950' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T03:00:00.000Z, have: '473178' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T02:00:00.000Z, have: '367840' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T01:00:00.000Z, have: '432800' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z, have: '339252' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T23:00:00.000Z, have: '387230' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T22:00:00.000Z, have: '394494' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T21:00:00.000Z, have: '418204' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T20:00:00.000Z, have: '367362' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T19:00:00.000Z, have: '413499' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T18:00:00.000Z, have: '349060' },
  { timestamp: 2024-01-24T17:00:00.000Z, have: '371978' },
  ...
]
```

some examples of the temporary `daily` table

```json
[
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/chats/{id}/messages',
    avgResTime: 746.3,
    requests: '550'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/users/notifications',
    avgResTime: 1672.49180327869,
    requests: '3172'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/users/me',
    avgResTime: 1810.5,
    requests: '2'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/users/me/settings',
    avgResTime: 485.537857367264,
    requests: '3183'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/users/{id}',
    avgResTime: 1003.1088978453,
    requests: '12902'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/messages/queue/stats',
    avgResTime: 6266.50378310214,
    requests: '1586'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/chats/{id}/media',
    avgResTime: 2225.42857142857,
    requests: '14'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/subscriptions/subscribers/count',
    avgResTime: 923.123957091776,
    requests: '839'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/subscriptions/count/all',
    avgResTime: 7739.31861198738,
    requests: '317'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/users/notifications/count',
    avgResTime: 858.5,
    requests: '2'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/users/list',
    avgResTime: 1666.56593406593,
    requests: '182'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/users/me',
    avgResTime: 1627.85657984921,
    requests: '17508'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/subscriptions/{id}',
    avgResTime: 1069.8,
    requests: '5'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/lists',
    avgResTime: 899,
    requests: '2'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/users/notifications',
    avgResTime: 2626,
    requests: '9'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/chats',
    avgResTime: 1582.53529411765,
    requests: '170'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'cron-na',
    resource: '/init',
    avgResTime: 4148.19227144204,
    requests: '3183'
  },
  {
    timestamp: 2024-01-25T22:00:00.000Z,
    region: 'api-asia',
    resource: '/chats/{id}/messages',
    avgResTime: 1788.10294117647,
    requests: '68'
  }
]
```

Comment: so.. it works for small dataset? just to clarify.

Comment: Slightly offtopic, I would merge the DELETE into the CTE using RETURNING, then do the aggregation in the CTE and INSERT the result. In that order in a single query you only touch the table 24h_metrics once, just the DELETE.

Comment: What does the `SELECT` in the CTE return for a small period of time? I suspect your grouping is duplicating data.

Comment: @BagusTesa I copied the whole 24h dataset into a test table and ran the query locally and it worked without an issue... So it works with a real-size dataset...

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've seen this recommended in other threads but it wasn't too detailed so I wasn't sure how this approach worked exactly... Could you link a source going into slightly more depth regarding this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver running the query in daily (if that's the CTE) with a before set to 23h ago (since it aggregates everything older than 24h so that's the smallest hourly dataset not yet aggregated / moved) I end up with a sum of 70k requests which is within expectation and also far from 300-500k. As stated in my post, testing the separate query parts locally didn't reveal any immediate anomalies as far as I could tell...

Comment: @Vale how did you create the local environment? using `sql` dump or `pg-dump`? i havent used postgres in the past few years, but i reckon indexes can be a bit inconsistent if you have a lot of row deletion and may require [manual `reindex`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html).

Comment: Perhaps have you some corruptions in indexes or tables. Runs pg_checksums on tables after a tests with an index rebuild...

Comment: 1) Using a type name `timestamp` as a column/alias name is confusing. 2) Add the query you used in your comment with filled in values and the output as text update to question. 3) How are you arriving at `300-600k` figure?

Comment: @BagusTesa uhm I'm honestly not sure what you mean. I copied the table for testing via the web interface of the db provider (supabase) and ran the query in the web sql editor and locally in the code...

Comment: @SQLpro could you go into a bit more detail what steps I should take in which order?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated my post to include queries and their results to illustrate the issue...

Comment: 1) Your first query is grouping by `timestamp` truncated to  hour and your second by the raw `timestamp` value. 2) Does the `timestamp`(again not a good name) field have values that are not at `00:00.000` time? If so I don't see how the second query gets the results it shows?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the `aggregate_metrics` table is populated with data from the `24h_metrics` table grouped by hour already (with the query I posted initially), hence why there's no need to truncate to hour in the third query...

Comment: Alright missed that. Then the issue is your first query should be a replicate of the query in the CTE(WITH daily AS) as that is was is populating `aggregate_metrics`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I can do that too but then it's kinda hard to grasp the data as there's several regions and resources so the hourly data is scattered much more...

Comment: Restrict the regions in your `WHERE`, two would probably due.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've adjusted / added another sample (partially) showing the data as you suggested

Comment: How many regions are there? How many resources? I'm sure you are multiple counting, just not how it is being done, yet.

Comment: Try: `select timestamp, region, count(*) from aggregate_metrics where timestamp = '2024-01-25T20:00:00.000Z'::timestamp group by region, timestamp, resource having count(*) > 1`

Comment: @Vale first use REINDEX to rebuild all your indexes, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html, last use pg_checksum https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgchecksums.html to verify hardware integrity of the storage This will need a lot of time. After that if any corruption is raised then move yours files to a sanity storage and check again the storage. If corruptions remains, restore an old backup and all the archive logs to recover your database at the last checkpoint. You can begin by CHECKPOINT and force an archive log to be sure to recover the last data in your db.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that query returned no results. As for the previous question, querying for distinct regions / resources returns 5 regions and 58 resources, but both (especially resources) could increase at any time...

Comment: Hmm. Before you attempt a `REINDEX` or checksum check I would try something else. Namely create a table that has the same structure as `aggregate_metrics` but a different name. Then run your original  query `WITH daily AS ( ...`, but insert into the new table. Then select from that table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the suggestion. I did some more tinkering and running the query to populate a new table works like a charm. The more I mess around with this, the more likely it seems this is something with the environment / configuration the query is executed in. We're using node sequelize ran inside an hourly cronjob but I still have a hard time wrapping my head around why and how this'd result in too many results given a transaction should prevent problems resulting from this (or so I thought).
One thing I noticed: the aggregated results seem to be multiples of the real value...